# How to detect changes made in the edited field in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-reactivity

I have an object like this:

```
users: {
    email: '',
    password: ''
}
```

When user edits something, I want to detect the changes made in the key of the `users` object & save that key in another object(say `editedFields`)! How can I do this?

I tried using deep watchers like this:

```
watch: {
    users: {
        handler: function(val, oldVal) {
            //
        },
        deep: true
    }
}
```

But I am not sure how to get that edited key! Please help

Answer (score 0):

I think this works:

```
watch: {
    'users.email': function(newEmail, oldEmail) {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: That's cool but there are like fifty keys in the object and I can't just do this. So, is there a another way? I mean just watching the object and getting the edited value?

Comment: I would say you’re probably doing something wrong – sorry to be blunt. Why are you duplicating data? You shouldn’t need to copy 50 variables, ever.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this might work?

```
data: function() {
  return {
    user: { 
      email: '',
      password: ''
    },
    editedFields: []
  }
},
watch: {
  users: {
    handler: function(val, oldVal) {
      for (var key in val) {
        if(val[key] != oldVal[key]) {
          this.data.editedFields.push(key);
        }
      }
    },
    deep: true
  }
}
```

But actually, there better way of handling this would be to create a new Vue component for each field. You can then test to see if its been updated in each component.